# requiring the user to input ... using Scanf

Tags: c

A requirement for part of my project is to create an array of random ints. It says the user needs to input the min and max of these random ints in this format min...max. It must be separated by 3 dots, however I can't seem to find anything on how to implement this in Scanf format.

```
printf("Enter the size of the array: ");
  scanf("%d", &N);
  printf("Enter the range min and max separated by ...: ");
  scanf(" %d, %d", &min, &max);
```

Comment: Have a look at `scanf()`'s format options : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanf_format_string#Format_string_specifications

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the dots in the format string so it knows to skip over them:

```
scanf("%d...%d", &min, &max);
```

Comment: I might add a space before the triple dots; the `%d` allows spaces after them, so symmetry suggests allowing spaces before too.